# error when running golang code, regex package is missing?

Tags: go

I'm trying to run some go (golang) code I have written and I keep on getting this error:

```
cannot find package "regex" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/regex (from $GOROOT)
    /gopath/src/regex (from $GOPATH)
```

Isn't regex included when one installs Go?

If not, where I can I find it and how can I install it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called `regexp`, not `regex`: http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/